# How to make a deep copy of my component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data file which should have the following structure:

```
let data={
    color:"#bf3636",
    count:2,
    inputs:{
             1:{value:value,type:type}
             2:{value:value,type:type}
             3:{value:value,type:type}
             etc
           }
}
```

I tried to figure out how to create such a structure but it didn't work. Here is one of the last options:

```
export  const mainReducer=(state=data,action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "color": {
            return {...state,color:action.color}
        }
        case "count": {
            return {...state,count:action.count}
        }
        case "inputs" :{
            return (action.typeOFInput==="radio")?{...state,inputs:{[action.i]:{value:(state.inputs.[action.i])?state.inputs.[action.i].value:"", type:action.typeOFInput}}}
                :{...state,inputs:{[action.i]:{value:action.value, type:(state.inputs.[action.i])?state.inputs.[action.i].type:""}}}

        }
```

What should I fix in order to create the given structure?

Comment: You can try looking up immutable JS, it'll help you avoid the confusion of spreading data and you can directly work with setIn and getIn for data manipulation.

Comment: Consider using [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    case "inputs" :{
        let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
        (action.typeOFInput==="radio")?newObj.inputs.[action.i]={value:(newObj.inputs.[action.i])?newObj.inputs.[action.i].value:"", type:action.typeOFInput}
        :newObj.inputs.[action.i]={value:action.value, type:(newObj.inputs.[action.i])?newObj.inputs.[action.i].type:""}
        return newObj

    }
```